# File isn't where locate says it is

Tags: apache2, locate

I'm trying to find a certain file for apache so I used the locate command to find it, however, when I go to the directory that locate says it is in, the file isn't there. Does anyone know why this might be? I've tried switching to the super user but it still doesn't show up. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `locate` command uses a database, which is updated about once a day. While it gives fast results, it isn't necessarily accurate. If `locate` says a file exists, but it isn't there, it was moved or deleted after the last database update. Also see [A file shows in “locate” command but don't exist. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/387638/a-file-shows-in-locate-command-but-dont-exist-why)

Comment: Upon completion, you can update it with updatedb command.